# Infinite scrolling through div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a div which shows what meetings there are today and in which room they are.

right now I show it via this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div id="room_content">
        <?php 
            $url = "Urlname :)";
            $content = file_get_contents($url);
            $json = json_decode($content);

            foreach($json->rooms as $room)
            {
                echo '<p><div class="rooms">' . $room->name . '</div></p>';
//Kijk of er afspraken voor die kamer zijn.
                $a = count($room->meetings);
                if ($a == 0){
                    echo "<div class='no_meeting'><u><p>No meetings planned in this room</p></u><br /></div>";
                }
//Laat zien wat voor afspraken er zijn
                foreach($room->meetings as $meeting)
                {
                    $start = $meeting->start;
                    $start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $start, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                    $end = $meeting->end;
                    $end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $end, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                    $duration = $meeting->duration;
                    $duration_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $duration, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

                    echo '<div class="meeting"><u><p><b>' . $meeting->subject . '</b></p></u>'; 
                        echo '<p><b>Organizor:</b> ' . $meeting->organizer . '</p>';
                        echo '<p><b>Start:</b> ' . $start_time->format('H:i') . '</p>';
                        echo '<p><b>End:</b> ' . $end_time->format('H:i') . '</p>';
                        echo '<p><b>Duration:</b> ' . $duration_time->format('H:i') . '</p><br /></div>';           
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this shows me the needed data.

Right now it is in a div which if needed scroll up and down automatically. This is done via JavaScript.

```
<script language="javascript">
   ScrollRate = 50;
 
   function scrollDiv_init() {
      DivElmnt = document.getElementById("room_content");
      ReachedMaxScroll = false;
 
      DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
      PreviousScrollTop  = 0;
 
      ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
   }
 
   function scrollDiv() {
 
      if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
         DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
         PreviousScrollTop++;
 
         ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
      }
      else {
         ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0)?false:true;
 
         DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
         PreviousScrollTop--;
      }
   }
 
   function pauseDiv() {
      clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
   }
 
   function resumeDiv() {
      PreviousScrollTop = DivElmnt.scrollTop;
      ScrollInterval    = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
   }
</script>
```

However, this is pretty annoying if the div is a little scrollable. This because it just bounces up and down.

My question:

Is it possible to instead of letting it bounce, to let it keep scrolling down? Like a news feed but then vertical.
This way it does not bounce, but keeps moving smoothly downwards.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the requirement, this can be achieved by keeping scroll to the bottom of div irrespective of the data.

```
 var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
 objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: What i want is that is keeps scrolling down. So for instance, the div is scrollable. i want it to scroll downwards infinite. So at one point the top has to go to the bottom etc.